# Augment keras model output and take as the input to a second model

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Iam trying to train a cascade model where I want to take the output of model1, augment it, and feed it into a second model.
If possible I want to train the two networks end-to-end.

Now Iam wondering if this is possible in Keras?

Thanks for any advice,

cheers,

M

Comment: You can easily implement this using the functional API. It allows you to have multiple hierarchical endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you perform the augment yourself (not within a generator), it's doable.

You can explore all sorts of custom functions inside `Lambda` layers and use these functions for augmenting. You can use any function from [Keras Backend](https://keras.io/backend/) as well as any function from your backend framework (Tensorflow, Theano, CNTK)

If your backend is Tensorflow, there are many functions available. [This link contains several examples of augmenting with `tf` functions](https://androidkt.com/tensorflow-image-augmentation-using-tf-image/).

You can build this as a single network, or as two networks joined, any way you like.

Example of single net:

```
inputs = Input(...)
out = SomeLayer(...)(inputs)
out = SomeLayer(...)(out)

...

out = Lambda(someAugmentFunctionYouDefine)(out)

...

out = SomeLayer(...)(out)

...

model = Model(inputs, out)
```

Works with sequential models as well.

Other options (such as a custom training loop with eager mode on, using functions that don't belong to your backend) would break backpropagation, I don't think you'd like that.

Comment: Perfect Daniel, that was exactly what I was looking for!
Thank you so much :-)